# UITableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath not called after programmatically selecting a row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am manually calling the method on `UITableView`

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

and the `UITableViewCell` is updating its look correctly for the selected state - but when the user presses the cell again , the delegate method `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` isn't called as expected but `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

A tap on an `UITableViewCell` always causes a call to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.
What you want to do is to handle select / deselect in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. So in there check if the tapped row is already selected, then manually deselect it. Otherwise it was a "normal" row tap and the row can be selected or whatever action you want to have there.

Comment: a tapped row will always be "selected" if you check -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; if (cell.selected) { // always true}

Comment: Track what indexPaths are selected in a NSMutableArray (or NSIndexPath if you only allow for one selected row), then you can check on that.